# TestComplete (Web module) .keys() method in IE11 missing some letters

Tags: internet-explorer, jscript, testcomplete

I have an issue with TestComplete 10.6 and IE11. While typing text to a textarea IE11 is missing some letters.

Simple example of the test:

```
function Test1()

    var textarea;
    Browsers.Item(btIexplorer).Navigate("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea");

    textarea = Aliases.browser.pageWwwW3schoolsComTagsTryitAspF.frameIframeresult.textarea;

    textarea.Click(264, 54);
    textarea.Keys("[Enter]the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
    textarea.Keys("[Enter]the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
}
```

The result is randomly missed letters. e.g.:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over thlazy dg
the quick brown fox jmps over the lazy dog
```

TestComplete Key pressing delay, ms = 250

I checked it on two different VMs and they produce the same issue.
I do follow the Smartbears IE documentation to [prepare the browser](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/72339/) before testing.

I added a comment [here](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/Functional-Web-Testing/Windows-8-1-related-problem-Keys-Method/td-p/82222) but there is no feedback so far.

Please let me know if you get the same results or that's something relating to my TestComplete configuration.

Comment: Everything works fine for me. I think that you need to contact SmartBear support with this issue: http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete

Comment: I'm waiting for their reply. If they'll come with a solution I'll post it here. Thanks @DmitryNikolaev.